# The Row Reducing Matrix with Complex Entries

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> $$\begin{pmatrix} -2i&-3&7\\ 0&-1-2i&5\\ 0&-1&1-2i \end{pmatrix} \mathbf{v} =0 \implies \begin{pmatrix} -2i&-3&7\\ 0&-1-2i&5\\ 0&0&0 \end{pmatrix} \mathbf{v} =0.$$

How do I get the second matrix? What're the steps?

How to do this matrix to RREF form?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Math.SE. Homework question are usually not well received, so you should provide context in order to receive help: what did you tried to solve this exercise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiply row 3 by $1+2i$. Then rows 2 and 3 will be the same and you can subtract row 2 from 3.